# How do I position JButtons vertically one after another?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I used a `CardLayout` to create 2 panels. The one on the left hosts `JButtons`, which when clicked, opens the corresponding website in the right panel. The problem is that I'm unable to place the buttons one on top of the other.

Please observe the screenshot below :-

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Use a different layout inside of the panels. They probably default to `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *"The problem is that I'm unable to place the buttons one after the other."*

You could use a [**`Box`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) set vertically

```
JButton jbt1 = new JButton("Button1");
JButton jbt2 = new JButton("Button2");
JButton jbt3 = new JButton("Button3");
JButton jbt4 = new JButton("Button4");

public BoxTest(){
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();    // vertical box
    box.add(jbt1);
    box.add(jbt2);
    box.add(jbt3);
    box.add(jbt4);

    add(box);  
}
```

Run this example to see

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BoxTest extends JPanel{

    JButton jbt1 = new JButton("Button1");
    JButton jbt2 = new JButton("Button2");
    JButton jbt3 = new JButton("Button3");
    JButton jbt4 = new JButton("Button4");

    public BoxTest(){
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box.add(jbt1);
        box.add(jbt2);
        box.add(jbt3);
        box.add(jbt4);

        add(box);  
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new BoxTest());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

> *"How about if I want to leave gaps between the buttons ?"*

To add space int between use [**`createVerticleStrut()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalStrut%28int%29) in between the components

```
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(jbt1);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));  <-- 10 being the space
    box.add(jbt2);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box.add(jbt3);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box.add(jbt4);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a ton. That almost solved my problem. How about if I want to leave gaps between the buttons ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Actually I was testing the same . This was the first time I queried on stackoverflow and got cent percent satisfied.