# Components in GridLayout don't show properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

I create a GridLayout Frame with 2 rows and 3 column. I put 3 JLabel in the first row and each column. When I try to run, the third label is in the second row and the first column as show below

[image: screenshot]

Why does it happen?

Here the code

```
  JFrame windows = new JFrame("Shop");
  windows.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
  JLabel prodlabel = new JLabel("Products");
  windows.add(prodlabel);
  JLabel spacelabel = new JLabel(" mid ");
  windows.add(spacelabel);
  JLabel shoplabel = new JLabel("Shopping List");
  windows.add(shoplabel);
  windows.setSize(1360, 728);
  windows.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Use a `Box`, it will maintain the preferred sizes. See [`This Answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20737349/2587435) to see how to use a `Box` it's _very_ simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the way GridLayout behaves when both the rows and columns are set to non-zero values. The LayoutManager decides on a column count itself based on the number of rows and the container's component count.

You can instead set the number of rows to 0 and set columns to 3. The LayoutManager will add more rows as you add more components to the container.

```
windows.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
```

Edit: Wording, and [here's a link to the Java Tutorial on GridLayout which may or may not have more information related to the matter.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you use `GridLayout` which resise component to whole cell(vertically/horizontally) and when you add component to that, it places them one by one firstly place components to row and them switching column, when row is full. You need to use another [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

For example try to use [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Or you can fix it by using one row`new GridLayout(1,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You set layout for 6 elements.
Try to add all 6 elements an run it